# How to start ksql in windows?

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

how to start ksql in windows environment?

we have installed confluent kafka using zip format. we have not found ksql-server-start.bat file in confluent-home/bin/windows directory, but we observed a file with same name under confluent-home/bin/ directory which is not a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. It's not a batch file.

In order to run on windows, you can either run using cygwin or bash shell. If you are using Windows 10,you must have bash shell.  Otherwise you can install one or cygwin.

It seems to be a known issue. You can refer it here :
https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/402

Answer (score 0):

I was "finally" able to get it to run... in two different command windows:

The server:

java -cp  c:\ksql-master\ksqldb-rest-app\target\ksqldb-rest-app-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain c:\ksql-master\ksqldb-rest-app\target\ksqldb-rest-app-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT-package\etc\ksqldb-rest-appksql-server.properties

The CLI:

java -cp  c:\ksql-master\ksqldb-cli\target\ksqldb-cli-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar io.confluent.ksql.Ksql http://0.0.0.0:8088